# Apache-NiFi Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception

Tags: csv, groovy, apache-nifi

I use `ExecuteGroovyScript` processor just to extract only wanted columns for my further calculations.

Groovy Code :

```
def flowFile = session.get()

if(!flowFile) return

flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
    outputStream.withWriter("UTF-8"){ w ->
        inputStream.eachLine("UTF-8"){ line ->

                 def row = line.split(';',-1)

                 w << row[0,1,6,8,9,11].join(',') << '\n'

        }
    }
} as StreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

But for some `csv`, I get **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**.

My csv :

```
id,name,email,address
1,sachith,sachith@email.com,{"Lane":"ABC Lane","No":"24"}
2,nalaka,nalaka@email.com,{"Lane":
"DEF Lane","No":"34"}
```

How can I get just 1 row and ignore other two rows? I have tried `ValidateCSV` processor for validating. But it can not capture this.

Comment: give the sample of csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to use `ValidateCSV` processor to validate the row. this is tricky because the `,` in the middle of `{"Lane":"ABC Lane","No":"24"}` will consider this field as 2 differents fields.

every invalids rows will be routed to invalid :

[image]

ValidateCsv processor configuration :

[image]

Schema :

```
ParseInt(),StrNotNullOrEmpty(),StrNotNullOrEmpty(),StrRegex("\{.*"),StrRegex(".*\}")
```

You should look at this processor documentation for more detail if you want a better schema :

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ValidateCsv/additionalDetails.html